# GIT, When pushing code to production, should I create a branch or?

Tags: git

I want to somehow tag the codebase when I push it to production, so that next time when I want to push to production I can do a diff and see exactly what files changed since the last time.

How can I do this with GIT?

Also, how can I list all production builds?

Answer (score 1):

1/ Remember than "pushing to production" is [not always the ideal way to put your code in a production environement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144670/using-git-below-web-root-in-production/3144865#3144865).

2/ You would have to use a [Git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the "server" side (i.e. here the Git on the production side, like the the `post-receive` one to put a [annotated tag](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging) on what you just received.
Those tags can be then fetch by the first repo, and used to `git diff` two of those tags.

Comment: I am not actually using GIT to move code to production server, sorry bad way of saying it.

Comment: @Blankman: all right, but then are you still pushing your data to another repo? (or actually merging them to a '`production`' branch within the same repo?)